# React Native (Hooks) - How do I 'cancel all subscriptions and asynch tasks in a useEffect cleanup funciton'?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

After doing some reading, I'm pretty sure this warning is being caused by a fetch request I'm making in my component.  Whenever I navigate away from said component (using React Navigation), I believe my fetch request results in an unresolved promise, caused by navigating away and thus my fetch returning a promise to an unmounted component.

```js
const MakePicker = (props) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([{text: 'Option 1'}]);
    const [selectorState, setSelectorState] = useState([{selectedOption: null}]);

    setDataHandler = (data) => {
        setData(data);
    };

    setSelectorStateHandler = (selectedOption) => {
        setSelectorState({selectedOption: selectedOption})
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchMakeData (makeId) {
            let response = await fetch('https://myAPIurlGoesHere', 
            {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            });
            let fetchedData = await response.json();
            return fetchedData;
        }

        fetchMakeData().then(fetchedData => {
            let data = [];
                for (const item of fetchedData.data) {
                    let dataObj = {
                        text: item.name,
                        value: item.name,
                        id: item.id
                    };
                    data.push(dataObj);
                }
                setDataHandler(data);
        })
    });

    return (
        <Layout style={styles.container}>
            <Select
            style={styles.select}
            data={data}
            placeholder='Select Make'
            selectedOption={selectorState.selectedOption}
            onSelect={setSelectorStateHandler}
            />
        </Layout> 
    )  
}
```

My component makes a Fetch request as soon as it's mounted. I did this on purpose, I'd like the items in my 'MakePicker' to be populated before the user even clicks the drop down. My problem is I don't know how to 'cleanup' or cancel subscriptions and asynchronous tasks. I know my fetch should go inside of the useEffect function, as this is what creates a side effect, and I know I'm supposed to return a function to 'cleanup' after. I just don't know what that means, or what it would look like. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Well, one problem that you're going to run into is that `fetch` is only just now adding an [abort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Aborting_a_fetch) API.  Effectively, you'll need to return a function that would leverage this API.

Comment: Should this effect only run once?

Comment: @MattSugden if you're asking if the Fetch is run only once? Yes, but it's whenever the user navigates to the screen this component is found on.

Comment: I can't see anything there that would need cleaning up. You don't have any variables defined in your effect that you can dispose/unsubscribe. Usually, to ensure an effect only runs once, you pass an empty array as a second parameter.